# Distiguishing between objects of the same class in Python

Tags: python, class, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Hello I'm trying to build a room planner and I'm struggling to find a way of telling between the different objects in the room

Here is the code for making the objects and the window:

```
from tkinter import *

class Object():

    def __init__(self, screen, pos, name):
        self.ob_xy = pos
        self.ob = screen.room.create_polygon(self.ob_xy)
        self.type = name

class Room():

    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = Tk()
        self.screen.geometry("800x500")
        self.screen.configure(background = "light blue")

        self.room = Canvas(self.screen, width = 500, height= 500)
        self.room.grid(row= 0, column = 0)

        self.objects = []
        self.objects.append(Object(self, [(50.0, 50.0), (50.0, 100.0), (100.0, 100.0), (100.0, 50.0)],"Stove"))
        self.objects.append(Object(self, [(150.0, 150.0), (150.0, 200.0), (200.0, 200.0), (200.0, 150.0)], "Table"))

Room()
mainloop()
```

Here is the code that I use to move the object around the canvas which I believe may be causing the problem
(self is referring to the object class)

```
def make_ob_range(self, ob_xy):
        '''finds the corners of the object'''
        self.max_x = 0.0
        self.max_y = 0.0
        self.min_x = 1000000.0
        self.min_y = 1000000.0
        for pos in range(len(ob_xy)):
            coord = ob_xy[pos]
            if (pos+1) % 2 == 1:
                if coord > self.max_x:
                    self.max_x = coord
                elif coord < self.min_x:
                    self.min_x = coord
            else:
                if coord > self.max_y:
                    self.max_y = coord
                elif coord < self.min_y:
                    self.min_y = coord

        self.mid_x = (self.max_x - self.min_x)/2 + self.min_x
        self.mid_y = (self.max_y - self.min_y)/2 + self.min_y

    ###The following coordinates work with moving the object around the canvas###
    def on_object(self, screen):
        """figures out if the mouse is on the object"""
        self.find_mouse_loc(self, screen)
        coords = screen.room.coords(self.ob)
        self.make_ob_range(self, coords)

        if self.mousex < self.max_x and self.mousex > self.min_x and self.mousey < self.max_y and self.mousey > self.min_y:
            self.object_moving = True
            self.move_object(self, screen)


    def move_object(self, screen):
        """moves the object around after the mouse"""
        while self.object_moving:
            coords = screen.room.coords(self.ob)
            self.make_ob_range(self, coords)
            if self.min_x < 0 or self.max_x > 500 or self.min_y < 0 or self.max_y > 500:
                self.object_moving = False
                self.move_object_into_canvas(self, screen, coords)
            else:
                self.movex = self.mousex - self.mid_x
                self.movey = self.mousey - self.mid_y

                self.mid_x += self.movex
                self.mid_y += self.movey

                #moves the object
                screen.room.move(self.ob, self.movex, self.movey)
                screen.room.update()

                #resets the mouse position and calculates the new coordinates
                self.find_mouse_loc(self, screen)
```

Comment: What is your expected output and what do you get instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uniquely identify python objects using `id()`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id

Comment: Do you know if there is a way of then calling the object after using id()?